# How to get the button's new position when placed to another one?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to assign an integer value to buttons that are produced from loops? What I want to happen here is to place the button pressed to a certain position when tapped, and when that button is tapped again, it will return to its original position.

I tried using the rooty or rootx method using a dictionary that saves the buttons original coordinates called origvals. Then comparing it to the button's new position when clicked, but it does not work, it instead gives me the same result. Can someone pls tell me of a best way to do this? Ive think of giving each button a 0 value and add that value 1 when it is pressed to make a modulus condition so that it would return when its pressed and go back to the certain position when pressed again.

```
from tkinter import *
import string
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')


# New Buttons coordinates when clicked
buttons = {}
# X coordinate after being clicked
ax=20
# Original Buttons coordinates; this must be their position once clicked again
origvals = {}


def Enter(Value):
    global ax
    print(buttons)
    print(origvals)
    print(buttons[Value].winfo_rooty())    

    if buttons[Value].winfo_rooty() != origvals[Value]:
        buttons[Value].place(x=ax,y=150)
        ax+=20
    else:
        buttons[Value].place(x=origvals[Value][0],y=origvals[Value][1])

    print(buttons[Value].winfo_rooty())

    print(origvals[Value])




letters = string.ascii_uppercase

# Original x and y position
a=100
b=300
c=100
# Placement of random letter buttons
for i in range(1,13):
    x = random.randint(0,25)
    if i > 6:
        buttons[letters[x]] = Button(root, text = letters[x],command=lambda val=letters[x]:Enter(val))
        buttons[letters[x]].place(x=c,y=330)
        origvals[letters[x]] = [c,330]
        c+=20

    else:
        buttons[letters[x]] = Button(root, text = letters[x],command=lambda val=letters[x]:Enter(val))
        buttons[letters[x]].place(x=a,y=b)
        origvals[letters[x]] = [a,b]


    a+=20

mainloop()
```

So you see, its kind of like a word game where you press each letters to form a word, and when one letter is clicked twice, it will go back to its original position.

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager - `place_info()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_info-method) and [Tkinter.Widget.bind-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind-method) and [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Should `buttons[Value].winfo_rooty() != origvals[Value]` be `buttons[Value].winfo_rooty() != origvals[Value][1]`?

Comment: As `x = random.randint(0, 25)` may generate same result in the for loop, therefore `buttons[letter[x]]` may overwrite previous one.